# how to adjust python script to turn on-off light specific hours

Tags: python, timer, raspberry-pi

I'am currently working on an project with Raspberry Pi 3 and I found a "working" code on the web but I am facing some issues.

I have to configure a relay-board so it will automatically turn on exterior lights at 18:00 and turn off at 06:00 with a variable so the times will change with a couple of minutes every day like;

Monday  18:00 - 6:00
Tuesday 18:05 - 6:15

I'm using Python to make and run a script.

My problem is when I run the script between these hours the code print the current hour,mins and seconds but dont turn on the lights, I found that the code "wait" until the next day and turn on at 18:00.

I tried to modify the conditional if ==
but i have no much experience coding

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import time
from random import randint
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

#Define Relay outputs
R1 = 19

#Define relay on times
R1ONH = 18
R1ONM = randint(5, 15)
R1ONS = 0

#Define relay off times
R1OFFH = 6
R1OFFM = randint(5, 15)
R1OFFS = 0

#Define GPIO mapping
Relay_ON = 19
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)   #Use BCM GPIO numbers
GPIO.setup(Relay_ON, GPIO.OUT)   #Relay enable


while True:
  dt = list(time.localtime())
  hour = dt[3]
  minute = dt[4]
  second = dt[5]
  time.sleep(1)
  print hour,minute,second;


  if hour == R1ONH:
    if minute == R1ONM:
      if second == R1ONS:
        GPIO.output(Relay_ON, GPIO.HIGH)

  if hour == R1OFFH:
    if minute == R1OFFM:
      if second == R1OFFS:
        GPIO.output(Relay_ON, GPIO.LOW)

GPIO.cleanup()
```

I wanna to make the script:

-work no matter if the device reboots the code will work between these hours

-make the script executable so it will run when device start up (I tried with rc.local) dont know if these the only thing I have to do for these.

Comment: For running a script on startup, you don't actually need to make it an executable.
Here is how to start scripts for Raspberry PI and most other Linux systems: https://www.dexterindustries.com/howto/run-a-program-on-your-raspberry-pi-at-startup/

Comment: Regarding GPIO control, you can use a pretty simple algorithm that takes the current time and decrement it till you get to one of the "alarm" values and act according to the ON or OFF. You need to handle the time values in a Cyclic manner.

Comment: someone help me by add these code:                                                                     
# test for relay current state
dt = list(time.localtime())
  if (hour >= R1ONH or hour <= R1OFFH):
    if minute >= R1ONM:
      if second >= R1ONS:
        GPIO.output(Relay_ON, GPIO.HIGH)                                                     
but i got these error: File "1.py", line 28
if (hour >= R1ONH or hour <= R1OFFH):
^
IndentationError: unexpected indent

I am noob with coding

Comment: In Python, the indentation is extremely important. Each time you have an if clause all the code that executes if the condition is true must be indented. Also you must use only one kind of indentation either spaces or tab but not both.